# How to submit flink streaming job to EMR?

Tags: apache-flink, airflow, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

I have few long running (streaming) flink jobs which I want to run on AWS EMR. I read the steps to do so from AWS console or using aws cli. But this is something manual. What are the ways to automate this in a production environment (where I can have multiple jobs and may need to handle failure scenarios as well)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit multiple jobs to an EMR cluster, you could use Flink's [REST API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html) to submit and monitor jobs. It uses the same port as the web UI, which you can access on EMR by following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/flink-web-interface.html).

If you want to spin up a new EMR cluster for each Flink job, you can use AWS's API or CLI.

Comment: Thanks David. Can I use airflow to automate this process? (Asking since, I haven't seen airflow being used to schedule streaming jobs)

Comment: FWIW, within the Flink community I mostly see folks implementing this sort of deployment and monitoring automation in the context of containerized infrastructures based on kubernetes. I haven't seen anyone using airflow with Flink.